# Zips and Zippers

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm currently reading *Differential Manifolds* by Antoni Kosinski, and the concept of a zip--defined as half of a zipper--is mentioned early on, of course with the intent of connecting manifolds. This seems very geometrically intuitive, but I cannot find a general, mathematical definition of a zip or a zipper. Would these geometric ideas be shown mathematically as the different methods which one can connect manifolds with, or does there exist a general definition?